# How do I unzip large files (>1Gb) from my Drive into Colab?

Tags: zip, google-colaboratory, unzip

I tried to unzip large zipfiles from my Drive into my Colab and got this error:

```
BadZipFile: zipfiles that span multiple disks are not supported
```

How do I unzip large files from Drive into Colab?

Answer (score 0):

Im doing that with two options:

```py
!unzip file_location -d file_destination #-d is for quite option.
```

Or other option more elaborate:

```py
import zipfile
from google.colab import drive

drive.mount('/content/drive/')

zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile("/content/drive/My Drive/ML/DataSet.zip", 'r')
zip_ref.extractall("/tmp")
zip_ref.close()
```